# Как можно сгенерировать option group через Js?

Tags: javascript

Передомной стоит проблема, нет доступа к редактированию Html разметки по определенным причинам, но нужно объеденить options из select в тэг optiongroup, к примеру, у меня есть пункты:

```
<select>
  <option data-group="first" value="test1">
  <option data-group="first" value="test2">
  <option data-group="second" value="test3">
</select>
```

Мне нужно преобразовать в:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="first">
    <option data-group="first" value="test1">
    <option data-group="first" value="test2">
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="second">
    <option data-group="second" value="test3">
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Проблема еще в том что этот селект кастомизирован через бутстрап. Возможно ли сделать такое через Js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var groups = {};

//собираем элементы по группам
$('option[data-group]').each(function(i, el) {
  var group = $(el).data('group');
  if (!groups.hasOwnProperty(group)) groups[group] = [];
  groups[group].push(el);
});

//оборачиваем в новый тег
for (var group in groups) {
  $(groups[group]).wrapAll('<optgroup label="' + group + '"/>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option data-group="first" value="test1">test1</option>
  <option data-group="first" value="test2">test2</option>
  <option data-group="second" value="test3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: супер спасибо, проблемка только что если в названии группы есть пробелы, он все слова после пробела отрезает, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: @zoinx2012 теперь не отрезает

Comment: привет еще раз, столкнулся с проблемой что этот код неадекватно select выдает, то есть допустим если я у первого элемента пропишу selected, на деле выбран будет второй, с чем может быть связано?

Comment: @zoinx2012 это как получилось? у меня не вышло воспроизвести